# How can I troubleshoot an Informix -255 "not in transaction" error?

Tags: glassfish-3, informix

Working with an Informix 11.70 database in non-ANSI, unbuffered logging mode.

I am accessing this database through a GlassFish 3.1.2.2 server with a connection pool set up to use `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` objects implemented by the `com.informix.jdbcx.IfxConnectionPoolDataSource` class.

All transactions are under the control of a JPA provider (Hibernate in this case), so there are no explicit `BEGIN WORK`, `COMMIT WORK` or `ROLLBACK WORK` statements that I have any control over.

In one particular deployment of this configuration, we are getting `-255` errors, which signify either:

- the database is in non-logging mode (this is not true in our case)
- the database is in some kind of logging mode, but there was a `COMMIT WORK` issued by someone without a preceding `BEGIN WORK` statement

How do I go about troubleshooting this problem?  What environmental factors would cause this error on one deployment and not on another?

Comment: I saw the question on the IIUG mailing lists too. Clearly, there must be a critical difference between the two installations. Either one of the software versions is different (perhaps you deployed a patched Hibernate on one and not the other), or the database is not the same on both despite you expecting them to both be logged, or the code running on the servers is not identical.  They're probably the main sources of variation; then there's always whatever is actually causing the trouble.

Comment: Indeed there must; that was my conclusion as well. I posted here in case there were some configuration item that would tell the Informix driver, say, to switch off transactions or something like that.

Comment: Curiosity, is the 11.70 on Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 1):

The answer thankfully has nothing to do innately with Informix or Hibernate support for Informix.  It has everything to do with obscure automatic data source creation in GlassFish that happens depending on how you deploy.  (This *may* have something to do with the default properties that the Informix data source supplies to the GlassFish web console.)

Specifically, we had a case where our deployer attempted to deploy our application on GlassFish without first creating the required JDBC resource.  GlassFish reported that some odd JDBC resources were missing: `jdbc/foobar__pm` and `jdbc/foobar__nontx`.

Our deployer, not figuring anything was wrong, created these resources by hand.  (GlassFish apparently ordinarily [creates these automatically](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24930/transaction-service.htm#beamu) when you deploy with its web console.)

As a result, our deployer had inadvertently specified a non-transactional data source for use by our application and that was the root cause here.